/dev/ttyACM0 permission denied on Ubuntu 24.04
I'm struggling to access an MCU connected to the USB and presented as a serial port: /dev/ttyACM0. What worked well in Ubuntu 22.04 does not work in 24.04.
Whenever I connect the device, the only way to have it access is to
chmod 666 it, but that works only temporarily.
The user I'm working on is already added to the dialout group, and ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 returns: crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Oct 25 15:33 /dev/ttyACM0 , so as I can understand it, it is the root who has r/w and any dialout group member.
Am I missing anything here to configure/add?

Edit:
The driver seems to be correct so that is not the case of invalid UDEV rule triggered:
[21856.363341] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[21856.761217] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=2e8a, idProduct=0005, bcdDevice= 1.00
[21856.761236] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[21856.761240] usb 3-6: Product: Board in FS mode
[21856.761244] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: MicroPython
[21856.761247] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: e6614c311b7f8c38
[21857.365083] cdc_acm 3-6:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[21857.365219] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[21857.365225] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters

Regards,
Piotr

After adding $USER to the supplementary group ''sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER'  did you log out and login again for it to take effect?

@david Yes, I have even restarted the machine a dozen times already. So far, the only solution is to use a parallel Terminal window and "chmod" it every time it restarts or when I reconnect it.

Is it possible that the /dev/ttyACM0 has already been claimed by another driver? Take a look at the answer in the following link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741536/how-to-create-a-dev-ttyacmx-for-a-given-device

Apparently, I do not think so because once permission is given with chmod , everything works fine; I can access RP2040 from within VSCode, and the REPL terminal works as expected. If the serial driver was invalid because the wrong Udev rule was triggered, I believe it would not work at all. I can give it a try, but honestly, as I have some experience with writing Udev rules, I have always struggled to trace which rule was triggered, so any help on how to trace it is appreciated.

The driver seems to be correct:
[21856.761217] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=2e8a, idProduct=0005, bcdDevice= 1.00
[21856.761236] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[21856.761240] usb 3-6: Product: Board in FS mode
[21856.761244] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: MicroPython
[21856.761247] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: e6614c311b7f8c38
[21857.365083] cdc_acm 3-6:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[21857.365219] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[21857.365225] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters


I think you already know more than me. My experience suggests what you have done should work.A long shot but I did notice there is a 'tty' supplementary group (aka 'dialup') (cat /etc/group) and wonder if adding this in addition to dialup might fix it.

Let me guess you have access with sudo. getfacl /dev/ttyACM0 please.

Here you are:
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/ttyACM0
# owner: root
# group: dialout
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---```
Nothing particular, I believe. I'm a member of the ```dialout``` (see original post)

Just a thought. Might you have two dialup groups? (one with a capital letter in it?)  What is the output of 'cat /etc/group | grep -i dialout'

Just one:
dialout:x:20:pczekalski```

This is only for current session. sudo setfacl -m g:dialout:rw /dev/ACM0 I think acl is missing for this device

What does the follow report? 'journalctl --since "2024-10-30 18:52" --until "2024-10-30 18:53" | grep ACM'     (Adjust time for just before manufacturing the condition and just after) If you get the time small enough remove the grep bit. Post answer to end of question.

@david, thanks for the reply. I'll give it a try; meanwhile, I've upgraded the kernel from 6.8.0-47 to 6.8.0-48 and ... the problem no longer exists. So it seems to be a kernel .47 specific problem.

Kernel upgrade: 6.8.0-47 to 6.8.0-48 helped to solve the problem.
